# "position: fixed" div is not fixed when parent rotates or translates

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

A `div` with `"position: fixed"` is embedded into a parent `div`. When the parent rotates or translates, the child `div` moves also.

Is it a bug? I expected the child `div` to remain fixed.

HTML snippet:

```
 <div id="mask">
    <div id="page">
    </div>
 </div>
```

See a repro at: http://jsfiddle.net/PseKK/

I know that I can fix it by applying the reverse transformation to the child `div` but for performance reasons in my real scenario, I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve extra-transformation.

Any idea how to overcome?

Comment: Can't you pull out the inner div? If not, why?

Comment: I can't because in my real scenario the parent div masks part of the child div.

Comment: You can pull out the inner div anyway. Do it, then play with `z-index` to place the mask above the page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a repost, the answer is located in this original question

[Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

Unfortunately it is a bug, but there seems to be a way to get around it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how to 'making the transformed div an image and using it as the background' as they suggest?

Comment: I believe they are saying is that instead of using CSS for your transformed div, use an image, and place it as the background within a fixed div, so you will have an image placed, instead of actual CSS for the transform shape. [Unfortunately thats not really a "fix", but sounds like there's nothing else to do.]

Comment: what do you mean "there seems to be a way to get around it" ? why can't you just write it as an answer if there is a way, instead or posting a comment as an answer?

Comment: The background image fix that answer proposes is a very niche solution.. clearly not applicable to all instances of a fixed element with a transitioned parent.

Comment: You should edit the answer and write what the way around it there is......