# How can I make an element sticky relative to the window without JavaScript (If Possible)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been loving `position: sticky`. It solves most, if not all, of the issues without resorting to JavaScript. But, I've hit a wall. I need to make an element that is nested inside a couple of `<div>` to be sticky. We know that `position: sticky` works as a blend of `position: relative` and `position: fixed`, therefore it will anchor to its first parent.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#sticky):

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the
>   document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor
>   and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor)

In this case, I want to make a header sticky relative to the window and not the container. The HTML makes it difficult for me to restructure it outside nested `<div>`

Is this possible without JavaScript?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="attendance">
<!-- Here's the header I want to make sticky to the window, and not to div.attendance-->
    <header class="text-center sticky">Monday 11/22/2019</header>
<!-- Header above -->
    <div class="date-config">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" id="workable" /> No Work<br />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="notes">Notes:</label>
            <textarea id="notes" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <label for="markall">Mark all as>
        <select id="markall" class="form-control">
            <option></option>
            <option>Absent</option>
            <option>Present</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="student-attendance">
      Hello :)   
    </div>

</div>
```

Any ideas?

P.S: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494943/1057052), but it uses JavaScript.

**Edit:**
[Here's an awful, but working example](https://jsfiddle.net/superjose/qsmeL0vk/) (Beware! It's in Spanish - Look for the dates! They won't stick to the window!).

Comment: can you also post your existing CSS so that we can run the code and see the current result?

Comment: @YongQuan: Sure! It's awful (Huge, and it's going to break your PC), but I added a jsfiddle with the exact code.

Comment: `position: sticky` is not supported in IE11. So be aware of that. Ideal approach would be to use `position: fixed` and let other element flow with defined margin-top.

Comment: @DineshPandiyan: Thanks ;) This is more of an enhanced feature, so it's ok if it doesn't work with older browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Ok! First I'd like to apologize as this question wasn't possible to be answered without rendering the HTML. Fortunately, **I have found the solution.**

**TL;DR** In this case, no, you need JavaScript. You will need to implement a `translateY` transform in the element to achieve this. I don't know if the problem is that the parent element has a transform property and it causes [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364486/1057052) or there's something else causing the issue.

**Explanation**:

I'm currently using a carousel JS library called [tiny slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider). I'm displaying form elements instead of images, (Building a responsive table; Had issues when I tried using CSS Grids). So far, so good. The problem started when I wanted to set `sticky` the date headers.

I went with the modern approach of setting `position:sticky`, but that didn't work. The elements would get clogged in a certain position and it wouldn't move or stick. I started researching online (which ended up asking this same question), and the HTML itself. I did find that there were many parent `<div>`s that were created by tiny-slider. My theory was that it was getting attached to one of those parents.

Therefore, I decided to try the old tactic of combining `position:fixed` with a `scroll` event. But, **that didn't work**. Going back online and Google-Fuing a bit, there seems to be an old bug [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9364486/1057052) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform) [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform) that whenever a translate is applied to one of the parents an out-of-root container is created and `position:fixed` doesn't work as expected.

*I have a hunch that this may be one of the reasons why sticky didn't work, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17773684/1057052), it doesn't seem like it.*

I kept thinking for a while, and resorted to use a `transform` CSS property with `translateY`. I made a small experiment in the browser, and it worked!

Hence, I ended up implementing the `scroll` eventListener and listening to the header's parent's position, and applying getBoundingClientRect() to get the offset. If I had applied it to the element itself, it would have given me the translated position which I applied through CSS.

I was skeptical that this could be a performance bottleneck for mobile browsers. Therefore, I checked that the transform function was called inside a `requestAnimationFrame` and it had applied a `will-change` property in the CSS **stylesheet**.

I ran the code with a 4x CPU Slowdown in Google Chrome, and had **good results** .

Here's the resulting function I have (Where elemsToFixed are all the `<header>` elements, and threshold is the top offset so it doesn't conflict with the navbar):

```
export function fixedHeaderScroll(elemsToFixed: HTMLHeadingElement[], threshold: number) {
  if (!elemsToFixed || elemsToFixed.length === 0) {
    console.error("elemsToFixed can't be null or empty");
    return;
  }
  console.log('Total elems', elemsToFixed.length);
  // We assume that all of the elements are on the same height.
  const firstEl = elemsToFixed[0];
  let propSet = false;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      const top = firstEl.parentElement!.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      if (top > threshold) {
        if (!propSet) return;
        propSet = false;
        setElemsFixed(elemsToFixed, top, threshold, false);
        return;
      }
      propSet = true;
      setElemsFixed(elemsToFixed, top, threshold);
    });
  });
}

function setElemsFixed(elemsToFixed: HTMLHeadingElement[], top: number,
                       threshold: number, setFixed = true) {
  console.log('SetElemsFixed is', setFixed);
  elemsToFixed.forEach((elem) => {
    if (!setFixed) {
      elem.removeAttribute('style');
      return;
    }

    elem.style.transform = `translateY(${(top * -1)}px)`;
  });
}
```

The following picture shows a 4x slowdown in the CPU and the calculation of the style (With 26 elements) is about 29.4ms (Which is great!). Using Chrome 70 on Windows and i7 4700MQ processor.

[image: chrome profiling 4x slowdown]

Comment: I want to make a correction. While I was driving, I realized that the translation is in fact taking too long. If it's a 60 Hz screen, each FPS is at 16.67ms. Therefore, it should be around that time. Nonetheless, I ended up applying a transition effect and it looks good.

Comment: I also want to make an addition, even though it says a 73.75% Global Usage (adjust for your needs) in caniuse, this could also be achieved with Web Animations API.

Answer (score 2):

As you reference to the docs, the position sticky will stick to its "nearest scrollable ancestor", which generally speaking will be any ancestor with 'display: block' (the default) and also things like 'display: flex'. You can make an ancestor not scrollable by setting **'display: contents'**. (Depending on the rest of your layout and CSS this may or may not be usable.)

Comment: Can you add a snippet explaining what exactly `display: contents` does that makes it suitable for this instance?