# CSS fixed positioning breaks in Chrome after -webkit-translate

Tags: css, webkit

I'm creating a webpage based on responsive web design. So when it's resized to a smaller resolution, the navigation menu will be removed from the top bar and turn into an iPhone Facebook/Path style mobile sliding menu. I've achieved it using [this](https://github.com/brewern/mobile-menu) library.

At the same time, I have a fixed positioning panel at the bottom, which can be pulled up and down, docked at the bottom of the page. It's very close to [this](http://web-kreation.com/demos/login_form_mootools_1.2/), just that mine is at the bottom and can be pulled up.

Here is the issue in Chrome: When I slide out the mobile menu and slide back in (it's using "-webkit-transform: translateX()"), the fixed positioned panel breaks its position.

After a bit of research, it seems to be [a bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574). **However, is there a workaround?**

Possible duplicate: [Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform) (I haven't found any workaround for my problem in the answer though)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can follow this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/stefanoortisi/DvZn2/1/

It's really clean and simple. You can start following the same structure.

Note:  the fixed element for some reason needs to have a z-index:

```
#topbar
    position: fixed
    z-index: 1
```