# css3 transform reverts position: fixed

Tags: css, css-transforms

When using a css3 `transform()`, `position: fixed` does not apply. I made a fully working jsFiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/SR5ka/

First scroll down, notice the left-hand sidebar stays fixed. Now, click `expand`, and scroll down, notice the left-hand sidebar is now **not** fixed.

Any idea if there is a native css fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a work around [**like this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/ft2d600s/). It involves toggling a left value (via a class) for both the fixed element and the container.

```
.global-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    transition: 300ms;
}
.global-wrapper.expanded,
.global-wrapper.expanded .navbar {
    left: 200px;
}
.navbar {
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    transition: 300ms;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    width: calc(100% - 170px); /* 100% - width of left bar plus margin */
}
```

With a small amount of vanilla JS to toggle it the class:

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector(".global-wrapper");
document.getElementById("expand").onclick = function() {
        wrapper.classList.toggle("expanded");
}
```

Comment: Didn't need the javascript.

Comment: So you didn't want the fixed element to shift over when the button was clicked?

Comment: Javascript is not needed, here is a pure `css` solution. Thanks for the inspiration. http://jsfiddle.net/SR5ka/25/

Comment: Ah, yes. I had thought about that just after posting. Glad to see I helped!

Answer (score 3):

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15251226/125264
This issue can be fixed by adding dummy -webkit-transform to the element which needs to be fixed. Worked for me.

**Edit 04.2016**

Looks like does not work anymore.

Comment: Ciprian, you are not alone, some guys on the linked answer have problems too.