# jQuery mobile: get navigation and search toggle position:fixed

Tags: css, events, jquery-mobile, mobile, position

I´m using jQuery Mobile and my navigation and search panel will slide from the left into the page. So the problem is, that something and I really don´t know what kind of element, is changing the position of the toggle so that it´s not fixed. I´ve defined already data-position:fixed; but that didn´t help.

How can I change the position of the jQuery Mobile toggles to position:fixed; so that they are over the div.ui-panel-dismiss ?

I know that jquery mobile uses translate3d to animate the panel. So if I put this out it will have the position:fixed; but the page will also stay behind the panel, so that is not a solution for me. But I think this question is like:
[css3 transform reverts position: fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059662/css3-transform-reverts-position-fixed)

Comment: you want to change .`ui-panel-dismiss` position? so you can access page while panel is open?

Comment: The panel uses translate3d (css3) to open the panel animated. So this CSS3 feauture I think is the reason for my problem. My panel-buttons are position:fixed; and every time I open the panel the buttons will stay position:fixed; in the DOM but look like position:static

Comment: It could be a jquery mobile bug or a CSS3 translate3d bug. I´m using Firefox by the way, so it´s not a webkit bug

Comment: maybe you should _unfix_ buttons once panel is open.