# Sidebar fixed panel with fixed content block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar which is **position:fixed;** and **overflow:auto;** - this causes the scroll to happen within the fixed element.

Now when the sidebar is turned on, that element does not move, its just static on the page.

**What i want to achieve**: I would like to fix **.super-image-thumb** inside the scroll element, so when the scroll happens, the thumbnails at the top are fixed.

I have tried a javascript fix as well but its still not working. Any recommendations?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('.super-image-thumb');
    if ($('.sliding-panel-content').scrollTop() > 100)
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '10px'
      });
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto'
      });
  }
  $('.sliding-panel-content').scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

```css
.sliding-panel-content {
    z-index: 1204;
}
.middle-content {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.middle-content {
    position: fixed;
    left: 8%;
    top: auto;
    width: 85%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-115%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-115%);
    transform: translateY(-115%);
    transition: all .25s linear;
}

.sliding-panel-content {
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.sliding-panel-content.is-visible {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-menu sliding-panel-content middle-content is-visible">
  <span class="closeBtn sliding-panel-close"></span>
  <div class="slide-content">


    <div class="super-image-thumb">
      <div id="product-gallery-super">
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=1">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=3">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=4">
        </a>        
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=5">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=6">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-image-container">
      <img class="main-image" src="http://placehold.it/500x2045">

      <button name="prev" id="super-prev">Prev</button>
      <button name="next" id="super-next">Next</button>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sohphie Rhodes, are you opposed to moving the  <div class="super-image-thumb"> group  outside (above) the <div class="js-menu sliding-panel-content middle-content is-visible">? This would result in a shorter scroll bar, is that an issue? Just asking to help folks consider solution requirements.

Comment: @CrisMooney Unfortunately not, the content is dynamically generated within the sliding panel content class.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed inside Fixed is always buggy. Let's just change `top`: http://jsfiddle.net/s31edgao/

```
function fixDiv() {
  $('.super-image-thumb').css({
      'top': $('.sliding-panel-content').scrollTop()+'px'
    });
}
$('.sliding-panel-content').scroll(fixDiv);
fixDiv();
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript for that will only make the things more complicated.

It is all about CSS, the `position: fixed` or `absolute` is always based on the first ancestor with `position: relative`, so you should play with it.

I would remove the jQuery code and add this CSS:

```
.slide-content {
    position:relative;
}
.super-image-thumb {
    position:fixed;
    background: #FFF;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.main-image-container {
    position:absolute;
    top:85px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

As in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2h7huvm/2/)

Comment: Hi, I like your answer, I also believe, that JS is not needed in this case, but is this working? I think, thumbs on top should be always fixed on top. And I tested your solution without success

Comment: I also would like to have the down vote justified by the author

Comment: @Francescoes. I downvoted - due to your CSS solution not making sense nor is it working on jsfiddle.

Comment: My confirmation: when I run the Fransesco es jsfiddle, the 6 images boxes at the top of the div continue to scroll with the scroll bar, which is what I read Sophie Rhodes as wanting to change.

Comment: Ok, my fault, I tested only on chrome and it works like a charm, Firefox doesn't like so much the `fixed` position, I trying to 'fix' it again

Comment: Thank you @Francescoes. Appreciate it! been struggling with this issue for a while

Comment: And my solution didn't work because of the transition bug in Firefox. The solution was valid, and actually I guess also the explanation with positions, may someone should remove the downvote - BTW fiddle edited

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `transitions` and `position: fixed` does not work together in all browser, when you remove them, code works fine. Some solution for this you can find in [css3 transform reverts position: fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059662/css3-transform-reverts-position-fixed)

I created snippet without transitions and also I removed JS part (I think is not needed), and propose CSS-only solution. It is not finished to the end, it needs some more aligments - but you can do it yourself - the way for solving your problem is clear, I think.

```css
.sliding-panel-content {
    z-index: 1204;
}
.middle-content {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.middle-content {
    position: fixed;
    left: 8%;
    top: auto;
    width: 85%;
}

.sliding-panel-content {
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.super-image-thumb {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}

.main-image-container {
    margin-top: 100px;   // should be same as thumb height
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-menu sliding-panel-content middle-content is-visible">
  <span class="closeBtn sliding-panel-close"></span>
  <div class="slide-content">


    <div class="super-image-thumb">
      <div id="product-gallery-super">
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=1">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=2">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=3">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=4">
        </a>        
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=5">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="product-gallery">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/61x79?text=6">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-image-container">
      <img class="main-image" src="http://placehold.it/500x2045">

      <button name="prev" id="super-prev">Prev</button>
      <button name="next" id="super-next">Next</button>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, you should citate me :) My solution didn't work because of the transitions