# Shift down / up position fixed elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a HTML framework that most of it's pages constructed from two section. first section (**TopPanel**) is a sliding panel that could slide down or up (with `jQuery` as well). second section is the **Main** part of page that could contain any sort of HTML document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--Meta scripts & more-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="TopPanel">
  <!--Panel's Contents-->
</div>
<div class="Main">
  <!--Some standard HTML docs here-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the **TopPanel** is sliding down, all elements of the **Main** section must move down. But it's possible to exist some `position:fixed` element in the **Main** section. so it's clear that they won't move unless we gave them some `margin-top: [$('.TopPanel').height()] px;`. But it's not what I'm looking after!

I'm looking for a way to shift down and shift up all content of the **Main** section with a smooth effect and without changing of all elements attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using a CSS `transform:translateY(20px)` on the `body` tag? If you are using fixed position on the other element, it shouldn't actually affect it although I haven't tested that.

You can then use transitions to get the smooth movement you are after.

```
body{
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:#fff;
  height:100%;
  transition:all .2s;
}

body.active{
  transform: translateY(60px);
}
```

Example:

http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/gpwPPo

Lookout for this kind of stuff though : [Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

Comment: Same idea :D
Should one of us remove the answer since they are both the same?

Comment: Interesting answer! but transforming body cause TopPanel shifting down as well. how to keep TopPanel position?

Comment: `position: fixed;` and negative height as `top` for **TopPanel** (for example: `top: -200px;`) solved the problem! thanx

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDEL](https://jsfiddle.net/ThermalCube/drz1LLan/) version
(UPDATED) Try this:

```js
$('.main').click(function(){
    $('.main').toggleClass('toggle');
})
```

```css
.main{
    width:20%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: rgba(100,100,100,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 12%;
    transition:all 1.0s
}
.top{
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(300,50,50,0.7);
    position: absolute;
}
.toggle{
    transform: translateY(100px);
    transition:all 1.0s
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="top">
        Top
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        Main
    </div>
</div>
```

It would need some tweaking but it still does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for is maybe this:

I have used JQuery UI 1.9.2 for making the toggle ease effect. For more i have created the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zm70mkx/2/)

**JQuery**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".topPanel").toggleClass("height", 300);
    $(".main").toggleClass("top", 300);
});
```

**CSS**

```
body { margin:0; }

.topPanel
{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#333;
}

.main
{
    top:50px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ddd;
}

.height { height:100px; }

.top { top:100px; }

p { font-weight:bold; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="topPanel">

</div>
<div class="main">
    <center><button>Click Me!</button></center>
    <p>Hey look at me, i am moving along when you click button!</p>
</div>
```