# I cannot get a header to be fixed at the top of the page on mobile (or small) screens

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a site for one of my clients (it is a WordPress based site, with a 'partially' customized template base on WooThemes - Hub ).

But now I cannot get my header/menu to 'stick' at the top of the screen on mobile of small screens (and my social-sharing at the bottom).

I've tried css fixed position, but it looks like it gets overruled (even though analyzing the site with te elements inspector shows the element is position:fixed; ).

`jQuery(window).scrollTop() => element.css('top')` replacement are not an option because of the recalculations the header bounces over the screen when you fast scroll on mobile devices.

The site address is [this](http://www.reclame.vormgegeven.nl/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what i found out  is that it is a well known and also very old bug that (at least on Chrome, i don`t know what about other browsers) -webkit-transform and fixed CSS-position do not work together.

> After some research, there has been a bug report on the Chromium
>   website about this issue, so far Webkit browsers can't render these
>   two effects together at the same time.
>
> I would suggest adding some Webkit only CSS into your stylesheet and
>   making the transformed div an image and using it as the background.

See this thread: [Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

Comment: Hi Marcel, I have made an overrule for the transform:none (since I don't use it anyway). will remove it completely  soon. Menu and social media is working great now. Thanks for the quick response.