# transition up with transform

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I have the following div with the following css

```
.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e8ebed;
    z-index: 600;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateY(100vh);
    min-width: 1024px;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

<div class="bottom"></div>
```

When the user clicks a button, I add the following class to the div:

```
.stuck{
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

I am expecting the div to transition upwards, but that is not happening. How can I get it to translate itself to the top of the screen using transform? Also, I need to translate it down afterwards at the same speed.

I add the stuck class to the div by doing:

```
$('.bottom').addClass('stuck');
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to apply the stuck class to the div.

Comment: done. see edited answer

Comment: Verify that your class is being applied correctly by opening developer panel while on the page.  (F12 in browser)  If the class is there, see the following link.  I think it might have to do with your position:fixed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform

Comment: _"but that is not happening."_ `css` and `js` at Question appear to return expected results. Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate `transition` not being applied?

Comment: Yeah from what I can see this should work, Either you have a js problem OR you have styles overiding it.