# Background Fixed Fullpage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm trying to set the background with the fixed property but I can not do it.

My code:

```
.background-page {
     Background: linear-gradient (to right bottom, # 2f3441 50%, # 212531 50%);
     Position: fixed;
}
```

Obviously it is wrong, but I do not know how to solve it.

Regards, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [`background-fixed` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp). But because fullPage.js uses by default css3 transformations when possible, you'll get some problems with some browsers which are buggy on this respect. See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

The solution to it is using the options `css3:false` or `scrollBar:true` in fullPage.js: