# Position fixed - not breaking out of document flow

Tags: html, css, frontend

Im pretty good with my css and i'd like to think i can figure why most things do what they do when it comes to frontend development. But i came across an issue today that I don't fully understand.

Heres the code:

```css
.nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.nav-open .nav-toggle:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<span data-action="toggle-nav" class="action nav-toggle">
         <span>Menu</span>
</span>
```

Here is a fiddle for it:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vm962be/1/

And here is the second fiddle with the transform commented out.

https://jsfiddle.net/0vm962be/2/

So you'll see the difference.

So, what i would expect to happen is the after would be 100% width of the body and 100% height of the body, when the parent element has a **.nav-open** class.

However because of 1 simple line of code (transform: translateY(50%)), this doesn't happen, what actually happens is the **fixed** element acts like a absolutely positioned element inside of the .nav-toggle and only goes 100% to its parent.

why would a transform on a parent have an impact of a fixed element? I though ***position: fixed;*** broke the document flow no matter what. And only listened to the window width height. I need to learn why this happened.

Any advice would be great. Links to specs etc?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this? I am having a hard time replicating your scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haha, that's funny. I had the same issue not that long ago.

Apparently, it's a bug in webkit browsers.
See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20574
As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637267/2632061

That means, there is no way this can work, unfortunately.
You could try something similar with flexbox probably but what are you even trying to achieve, it's not 100% clear to me just from that fiddle.

> In the HTML namespace, any value other than none for the transform
>   results in the creation of both a stacking context and a containing
>   block. The object acts as a containing block for fixed positioned
>   descendants.

This means that fixed positioning becomes fixed to the transformed element, rather than the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I really was scratching my head over it, and i couldn't find anyone with the same issue. Looks like it'll have to be a top:5px; instead then haha.

Answer (score -1):

Use vh and vw instead percent:
https://jsfiddle.net/93ybxgau/1/

```
.nav-open .nav-toggle:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: No thats not the answer to the problem. Im asking why. Not asking how to fix it.