# position: fixed not working

Tags: css, browser

Working on a website today I found myself in the position (haha...) that a logo that I wanted to fix to the viewport didn't stick anymore. In my research to resolve this problem I learned that `position: fixed` won't fix to viewport if the ancestor element has a transform on it (see [positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)).

I made sure not to have any transforms on my element (or it's ancestors), I even tried to remove all child elements (which happen to have transforms and animations on them) – but I still didn't manage to get things going.

I am sort of clueless right now, so I made a jsfiddle for others to look at. The element that needs fixing is the bright red `.titles` element: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWcD9/90/

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Yeah, hundreds of lines of code is a bit much; I'm sure you can demonstrate the issue with less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove transfrom from body

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    /* -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); */
    /* transform: translateZ(0); */
}
```

Comment: Good find! Found it myself just a minute before.