# Position fixed don't work when scrolling parent div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a button `fixed` inside of `outer` div. The problem is when I set `position: fixed`(to keep the button stay while the page is scrolling) it didn't work properly.

The button still scrolled and moved out of the screen.

here is my code

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotate">
  <button class="fixed"> I am fixed inside a rotated div.</button>
</div>
<!--   <div class="fixed"> I am fixed outside a rotated div.</div> -->
```

How can I fix it to keep button always display on the screen while scrolling the page?

Comment: this is due to the rotation. You may apply the rotation to the button instead

Comment: @TemaniAfif I see, can it be fixed regardless the rotation or not?

Comment: i don't know how to explain this, but it's seems that the rotation break the position property. The only solution i see it to make the transform to the inner elements and not outer elements ... but maybe more experienced people will give you a better one :)

Comment: View it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is either a buggy or by design behavior by the browsers: basically, and "position: fixed" fixed element won't be fixed if any parent element has "transform" set. The following thread has some reference on it:

[Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

As for a workaround, you might use a  as a wrapper and nest the colored  and the  rotated inside it, then adjust the  positioning with "margin". It's kinda hacky, but it might work depending on the situation. Here's a demo:

```
[http://codepen.io/jean-andreghetto/pen/OxEaVN?editors=1100][2]
```

Comment: 5 years later and this solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have the fixed element inside of the static box, which means you made the red link fixed to the blue box, and not to the outside.  What you need to do is remove the red link of inside the blue box.

This should be what you want.

https://codepen.io/dawsonhudson17/pen/jGKeRy

```
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: blue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%) rotate(30deg);
  display: block;
  }

  <button class="fixed"> I am fixed inside a rotated div.</button>

  <div class="rotate">
  </div>
```