# How to force position fixed when parent container has a transformation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to apply position fixed to the viewport of a child div inside a parent which has a transformation applied.
Unfortunately I cannot remove the transformation on the parent.

- Any ideas how to overrides this behavior?
- Can I use transform on the child element to make it looks similar to position fixed?

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: blue;
   width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
padding: 10px;
color: white;
 top: 50px;
  }
```

```html
  <html>
  <body>
<div class="rotate">
<div class="fixed"> I am fixed inside a rotated div.</div>
</div>
  <div class="fixed"> I am fixed outside a rotated div.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want the fixed element inside the div to be the same as the fixed element outside?

Comment: @Swellar Yes, correct!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

Comment: and this answer explain well https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256339/2724173

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is simple this is not possible with CSS. Visit the following question for details

[Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

['transform3d' not working with position: fixed children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194313/transform3d-not-working-with-position-fixed-children/15256339#15256339)

But you can achieve your target with js here is a basic example.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".transform-fixed").css({
        "top": $(window).scrollTop()
    });
})
```

```css
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  background: blue;
   width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="rotate">
    <div class="fixed transform-fixed"> I am fixed inside a rotated div.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="fixed"> I am fixed outside a rotated div.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This answer assumes the dev uses JQuery, which is not good.

Comment: The Author assumes the person who knows basics can convert jQuery into JavaScript :)

Comment: @IsmailFarooq not asume that