# How do I force a sticky navbar to "overlay" its content

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, sticky

Let's say I have a navbar like the following:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50px);
  /* An example transform (I can't use position: fixed) */
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}

.navbar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar sticky">
  </div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

As you can see before scrolling, the sticky navbar is initially above the content paragraphs. However, if the navbar class is changed from `sticky` to `fixed`, then the navbar does overlay the content (like I want), but it does not scroll with the container, since it is transformed.

**How do I force sticky navbar to place the content after it underneath it so that it always behaves like an overlay to the content after it?**

**If the above isn't possible, then how do I force a fixed navbar to scroll with the user in a transformed container?** Note that I want to avoid something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47327617/6525260) (which is what I am currently using), because it results in jittery movements on the fixed container when scrolling.

Comment: You'd need JS to switch `sticky` to `fixed` once the conditions are met. CSS can't do that,.

Comment: @Paulie_D So there's no way for a position: sticky object to initially be on top of the content after it?

Comment: No...sticky doesn't overlay content as such AFAIK nor is it intended to.

Comment: @Paulie_D that's... unfortunate. Is there any alternative with position: fixed that doesn't require me to constantly update the navbars position with JS?

Comment: unless you set a negative `margin-top` of the sticky navs height to the first element after the nav (`.navbar + * { margin-top: -50px;}`). but probably not ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting the height of the navbar from the navbar with margin-bottom will work.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(50px);
  /* An example transform (I can't use position: fixed) */
  background-color: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.navbar {
  --navbarheight: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--navbarheight);;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  margin-bottom: calc(0px - var(--navbarheight)); /* or -50px in other words */
}

.navbar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar sticky">
  </div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```