# how does fixed position work when put it inside a relative position

Tags: javascript, html, css

According to this [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left):

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the left property specifies the distance between the element's left edge and the left edge of its containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor to which the element is relatively positioned.)

I put a fixed element inside a relative element, and set its 'left' property to some value.This value should relative to its parent div. But it doesn't work as expected. see my codepen: https://codepen.io/iamnotstone/pen/PgdPrJ?&editable=true

The text should inside the red box.

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.test {
  width: 500px;
  height: 132px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px
}

h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <h1>Fixed positioning</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `position:fixed` is fixed to the window. If you leave out the left or top property, it will adhere to its parent, otherwise no.

Comment: But how to explain that statement in mozilla ? @StackSlave

Comment: They are incorrect, on the matter of `position:fixed`. By the way, check out your link. I found the page, but I had to laugh.

Comment: Oh! thanks for mention that link  @StackSlave

Comment: I found something very interesting ! If I set a transform property in its parent. everything just works as expected!@StackSlave

Answer (score 3):

According to the doc: [`Fixed positioning`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#fixed-pos)

> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport.

Instead of *left* you can use *margin-left* property:

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.test{
  width: 500px;
  height: 132px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px
}


h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <h1>Fixed positioning</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why I can not put a left inside a left ?

Comment: @欧阳维杰, *left* is only applicable for elements set with *absolute* or *relative* positioning...:)

Comment: So that statement in mozilla is somewhat meaningless ?

Comment: @Mamun, I think you generalize a bit too much with your statement. The left property does apply to elements using `position: fixed`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) and a simple [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/25dr18bu/)

Comment: @NicoO, it is strange, what the document says, I could not make it work!!!

Comment: You seem to be correct about a mistake in the docs (see discussion above). I think [w3c.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#fixed-pos) delivers the best description: `Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning. The only difference is that for a fixed positioned box, the containing block is established by the viewport.`

Comment: Hey friends! When I added a transform property in its parent. everything just works as expected!  @Nico

Comment: This works because: In `absolute` or `fixed` positioned elements, if you omit positional properties (`left` and `right` for x-axis and `top` and `bottom` for y-axis), these elements take that position, which they would have with `static` positioning

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange. When I set a transform property inside its parent, everything just works as expected!

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.test{
  width: 500px;
  height: 132px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  transform: translate(0) /* added this, and works as expected */
}


h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>
  <h1>Fixed positioning</h1>
</div>
```

finally , I found the answer.

There is also a statement [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block):

> 1. If the position property is fixed, the containing block is established
>    by the viewport (in the case of continuous media) or the page area (in
>    the case of paged media).
> 2. If the position property is absolute or
>    fixed, the containing block may also be formed by the edge of the
>    padding box of the nearest ancestor element that has the following:
>
>    A transform or perspective value other than none
>
>    A will-change value of transform or perspective
>
>    A filter  value other than none or a will-change value of filter (only works on Firefox).
>
>    A contain value of paint (e.g. contain: paint;)

Comment: This is a bug in Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform

Comment: Yes, exactly ! So it is better to avoid transform property on parent element@yunzen

Comment: @yunzen it's not a bug, it's by design: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256339/8620333

Comment: I found this :  If the position property is absolute or fixed, the containing block may also be formed by the edge of the padding box of the nearest ancestor element that has the following:
A transform or perspective value other than none
A will-change value of transform or perspective
A filter  value other than none or a will-change value of filter (only works on Firefox).
A contain value of paint (e.g. contain: paint;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `position: fixed;` you are defining the position of an element in the viewport. If you use `position: absolute;` then you are defining the position of an element in its parent's box. Also CSS prioritises code lower down, so for example in your code `h1` is the most prioritised element (does not apply for classes and ID's, Classes take priority over elements and ID's take priority over classes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: fixed` for the document's body and use `position: absolute` for the elements with the parent which has `position: relative`, so change h1's position to absolute :

```
body {
  width: 500px;
  height: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.test{
  width: 500px;
  height: 132px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  transform: translate(0) /* added this, and works as expected */
}


h1 {
  position: absolute;   // 
  top: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0px
}
```