# Smooth / Momentum Scroll on window without a container

Tags: javascript, css, smooth-scrolling, momentum

I'm trying to simulate the buttery scroll on mac os / ios, often referred to as "inertia scroll" or "momentum scrolling", as you're going through the page.

Everything I found so far uses a transform3d to shift your content around and they manipulate this through some easing js function.

The issue with using a transform3d is that you can't use `position: sticky` or `position: fixed` anywhere in your app, thanks to this beauty: [Positions fixed doesn't work when using -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637058/positions-fixed-doesnt-work-when-using-webkit-transform)

I'm trying to figure a less intrusive way to build the same functionality, except without the container that all of these libraries are using.

I've tried a lot of things from messing around with the existing window scroll event to emit a new one with smooth scroll, hopefully with the right inertia values, to researching a way to do this via pure css.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Comment: Hi David, Your question was asked about 4 months ago. Did you manage to find the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually going through the same thing right now, it's funny that this question popped up right as I was looking for a solution.

The only thing I found thus far is to use this: https://github.com/BCJdevelopment/butter.js

My fixed position element is the navigation bar. It becomes fixed on scroll.

So what I did was I encapsulated all my scrollable body content, after my navigation bar, in a DIV with a "button" ID.

On scroll, the navigation bar turns fixed but the rest of the content is scrollable.

```
<body>
    <div class="fixed-navigation-bar"> ... </div> <!-- The position fixed element -->
    <div id="butter"> <!-- The JS targets this and everything within it has smooth scrolling enabled -->
        <div class="rest-of-website-content"> ... </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This works, but on Chrome the scrolling is super laggy and I'm searching for a solution with better performance.

Hope this helps at least a bit.